showing that a 2-form is multiplicative
I want to proof that that the 2-form $\omega_{(g,x)}\in \Omega^2(G\ltimes G)$ guven by
$$\omega_{(g,x)} = -\frac{1}{2} [\langle \text{Ad}_x \text{pr}^*_1 \theta_L, \text{pr}^*_1 \theta_L \rangle + \langle \text{pr}^*_1 \theta_L, \text{pr}^*_2(\theta_L + \theta_R) \rangle]$$
is mltiplicative. Where $\theta_L$ is the left invariant maurer cartan form and $\theta_R$ is the right invariant maurer cartan form.
What I have been tryig to do is the following, I want to show that $m^*\omega=pr_1^*\omega+pr_2^*\omega$, so so, take $X_{((g,x),(h,y))},Y_{((g,x),(h,y))}\in (G \ltimes G)_2$ so $X_{((g,x),(h,y))}=((X_g,X_x),(X_h,X_y))$ and $Y_{((g,x),(h,y))}=((Y_g,Y_x),(Y_h,Y_y))$
\begin{align*}
    (m^*\omega)_{((g,x),(h,y))}(X_{((g,x),(h,y))},Y_{((g,x),(h,y))}) =& (m^*\omega)_{((g,x),(h,y))}(((X_g,X_x),(X_h,X_y)),((Y_g,Y_x),(Y_h,Y_y)))\\
    =&\omega_{(gh,y)}(dm((X_g,X_x),(X_h,X_y)),dm((Y_g,Y_x),(Y_h,Y_y))) \\
    =&\omega_{(gh,y)}((X_{gh},X_y),(Y_{gh},Y_y))\\
    =&\omega_{(gh,y)}(((dL_g)_h(X_h)+(dR_h)_g(X_g),X_y),((dL_g)_h(Y_h)+(dR_h)_g(Y_g),Y_y))
\end{align*}
$$=-\frac{1}{2} \langle \text{Ad}_y (\theta_L)_{gh}((dL_g)_h(X_h)+(dR_h)_g(X_g)),(\theta_L)_{gh}((dL_g)_h(Y_h)+(dR_h)_g(Y_g)) \rangle$$
$$+ \langle (\theta_L)_{gh}((dL_g)_h(X_h)+(dR_h)_g(X_g)), (\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2} \langle \text{Ad}_y (\theta_L)_{gh}(dL_g)_h(X_h)+\text{Ad}_y (\theta_L)_{gh}(dR_h)_g(X_g),(\theta_L)_{gh}(dL_g)_h(Y_h)+(\theta_L)_{gh}(dR_h)_g(Y_g) \rangle$$
$$+ \langle (\theta_L)_{gh}(dL_g)_h(X_h)+(\theta_L)_{gh}(dR_h)_g(X_g), (\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2} \langle \text{Ad}_y(\theta_L)_h(X_h)+\text{Ad}_y\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}} (\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L)_h(Y_h)+\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(Y_g) \rangle$$
$$+ \langle (\theta_L)_h(X_h)+\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(X_g), (\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2} \langle \text{Ad}_y(\theta_L)_h(X_h), (\theta_L)_h(Y_h)\rangle+\langle \text{Ad}_y(\theta_L)_h(X_h),\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(Y_g)\rangle$$
$$+\langle\text{Ad}_y\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}} (\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L)_h(Y_h)\rangle+\langle\text{Ad}_y\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}} (\theta_L)_g(X_g),\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(Y_g)\rangle$$
$$+ \langle (\theta_L)_h(X_h),(\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle+\langle \text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2} \langle \text{Ad}_x(\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L)_g(Y_g) \rangle+\langle \text{Ad}_y(\theta_L)_h(X_h),\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(Y_g)\rangle$$
$$+\langle\text{Ad}_y\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}} (\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L)_h(Y_h)\rangle+ \langle (\theta_L)_h(X_h),(\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle+\langle \text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle$$
$$-\frac{1}{2} \langle \text{Ad}_y(\theta_L)_h(X_h), (\theta_L)_h(Y_h)\rangle+\langle (\theta_L)_h(X_h),(\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2} \langle \text{Ad}_x(\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L)_g(Y_g) \rangle+\langle \text{Ad}_y(\theta_L)_h(X_h),\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(Y_g)\rangle$$
$$+\langle\text{Ad}_y\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}} (\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L)_h(Y_h)\rangle+ \langle (\theta_L)_h(X_h),(\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle+\langle \text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle$$
$$+(pr_2^*\omega)_{((g,x),(h,y))}(X_{((g,x),(h,y))},Y_{((g,x),(h,y))})$$
but I still need to prove that
$$\langle(\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L + \theta_R)_x(Y_x) \rangle=\langle \text{Ad}_y(\theta_L)_h(X_h),\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(Y_g)\rangle$$
$$+\langle\text{Ad}_y\text{Ad}_{h^{-1}} (\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L)_h(Y_h)\rangle+ \langle (\theta_L)_h(X_h),(\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle+\langle \text{Ad}_{h^{-1}}(\theta_L)_g(X_g),(\theta_L + \theta_R)_y(Y_y) \rangle$$
, how can I do it? Can someone help me please? Thank you in advance.
